# Which approach to use MVVM or Static

Tags: mvvm, windows-phone-8

Im pretty new in using the MVVM architecture and looking for some advice on the "correct" to approach this task.

2 page app. 
Page 1 displays the alphabet.
Page 2 displays the selected character's details.

Example - Select "A" and screen 2 displays apple, Apricot, Aprium. Select "B" screen 2 displays Banana, Blackberry, Blackcurrant, Blueberry.

Data is being retrieved from a web service everytime the user selects an alphabet character.

Would the correct approach be to create a static menu for screen 1 (as you would never have anything else other than the alphabet characters) and on the click event load the second screen with the items as above using the MVVM approach (i.e. pass in the selected character to the LoadItems method). Or is there a simpler way to do this using a MVVM structure?

Ive read around and its not very clear on when to use which approach but then again as i say im new with MVVM too and would like to learn the correct/preferred way so i can get a better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft  actually prefers that when you use a list in windows phone it is always better to display it in another page. So you should populate the list in another page. And if you are selecting some thing to show then pass them as parameters using the `NavigationService.Navigate` or store the data in Phone Application State if you have to use app wide. `Phone.Application.Resources` . Its good that you are going through Mvvm You'll know Xaml, WP7,8, Get Metro Application Idea also Silverlight.

Heres a toolkit that might help you. It also displays the same way in a new Windows Not a popup

[Long List Selector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj244365%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for that. My research did originally lead me to believe using a LLS may not be the correct approach. So are you suggesting using the LLS as described in that link but adding each item to the jumplist? If yes doesn't that mean querying the web service at the start of the app to download the items? Which would increase bandwidth usage for users? Assuming each character would have around 50 items each? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another approach which maybe more in-keeping with the Windows Phone experience would be to have a single page containing a LongListSelector. Fruit bound to this view could then be grouped by letter. Implementing a JumpList would allow users to quickly navigate this list by jumping between groups. You can find a sample implementation here- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj244365(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks Andy that was the same link as above.